# sloccount or similar tool which can work on .deb packages without decompression?

Tags: source-code

AFAIK deb packages are ar archives.

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/example] - [10297]
└─[$] ls

libcpuid14_0.4.0_amd64.deb

┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/example] - [10298]
└─[$] ar x

libcpuid14_0.4.0_amd64.deb

┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/example] - [10299]
└─[$] ls

control.tar.gz  data.tar.xz  debian-binary  libcpuid14_0.4.0_amd64.deb
```

Now there is sloccount which is used for counting physical source lines of code (SLOC) as well as quantifying how much it would be needed to create if it was done commercially .

A project's figure -

```
SLOC    Directory   SLOC-by-Language (Sorted)
23697   src_modes       cpp=23697
12608   src_engine      cpp=12608
9584    src_luabind     cpp=9584
7269    src_common      cpp=7269
5294    src_editor      cpp=5294
3162    game            sh=3162
1721    src_top_dir     cpp=1598,objc=123
1425    top_dir         sh=1425
41      txt             sh=25,sed=16
0       HoA.xcodeproj   (none)
0       autom4te.cache  (none)
0       doc             (none)
0       img             (none)
0       lib             (none)
0       lua             (none)
0       m4              (none)
0       mus             (none)
0       snd             (none)


Totals grouped by language (dominant language first):
cpp:          60050 (92.67%)
sh:            4612 (7.12%)
objc:           123 (0.19%)
sed:             16 (0.02%)




Total Physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC)                = 64,801
Development Effort Estimate, Person-Years (Person-Months) = 15.97 (191.59)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Person-Months = 2.4 * (KSLOC**1.05))
Schedule Estimate, Years (Months)                         = 1.53 (18.42)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Months = 2.5 * (person-months**0.38))
Estimated Average Number of Developers (Effort/Schedule)  = 10.40
Total Estimated Cost to Develop                           = $ 2,156,763
 (average salary = $56,286/year, overhead = 2.40).
SLOCCount, Copyright (C) 2001-2004 David A. Wheeler
SLOCCount is Open Source Software/Free Software, licensed under the GNU GPL.
SLOCCount comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, and you are welcome to
redistribute it under certain conditions as specified by the GNU GPL license;
see the documentation for details.
Please credit this data as "generated using David A. Wheeler's 'SLOCCount'."
```

Is there some tool like sloccount which can read deb packages without the need to decompress or does decompression in-memory and gives the output such as above ?

Comment: Not a solution (yet?) but a recent development: http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=7362

Answer (score 1):

Cloc ? Available from Repository.

> Count physical lines of source code in the given files (**may be
>   archives such as compressed tarballs or zip files**) and/or
>   recursively below the given directories.

"cloc has a couple of features I like. For one, cloc can work straightaway on a compressed file. You don’t need to extract an archive before cloc does its thing; cloc will handle the decompression automatically. And if it runs into trouble, you can assert your biological superiority and tell it which decompresser to use." --- https://inconsolation.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/cloc-clock-your-code/